# Why is osmium the densest known element?

Tags: physical-chemistry, elements, periodic-trends

Why is osmium so dense despite there being heavier elements after it in the periodic table?

Comment: Is there any agreement as to whether Iridium is denser or Osmium? They're very close.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The density of an element is related to how many atoms can be placed in a given volume **and** the weight of the nuclei.  Therefore, the smaller the atomic radius of an atom **and** the higher the atomic number of the nucleus, the greater the density of the element. The very small atomic radius of osmium results in a small metal-metal separation.  This small atomic separation along with osmium's relatively high atomic number gives rise to osmium's high density.

**The small atomic radius can be attributed to the following factors**:

- f orbitals are very diffuse and therefore result in poor screening of the electrons further out.  In the case of osmium ($\ce{[Xe] 4f^{14} 5d^6 6s^2}$) the poor screening by its 4f orbitals leads to a contraction in the n=5 and n=6 orbitals.
- Due to osmium's high atomic number, relativistic effects come into play.  These relativistic effects have been discussed previously on SE Chem for [gold](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/16633/why-is-gold-golden/16637#16637) and [mercury](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/13667/why-does-mercury-have-low-melting-and-boiling-points/13671#13671).  A general discussion as well as the mathematics describing the relativistic effect can be found in these earlier posts.  Basically, for heavy nuclei the s electrons must circulate at relativistic speeds in order to maintain a stable orbit (not fall into the nucleus).  Therefore the electron mass increases and the s orbital radius decreases (the p orbital radius also decreases, but to a lesser degree).

The orbital contraction caused by these two effects leads to a small atomic radius for osmium.  Therefore, short metal-metal bonds result.  This is reflected in the **small unit cell volume for osmium (27.96 cubic angstroms)**.  For comparison the unit cell volume for **lead is 121.3 cubic angstroms!** As a result, more osmium atoms can pack into a given volume compared to other elements

**Osmium's relatively high atomic number along with its small atomic radius, as explained above, gives rise to osmium's high density**.

Comment: That, and the fact that it has a close-packed structure.

Comment: Do the relativistic effects reduce the OVERALL size if the atom or just the inner s orbitals (and slightly p)? so basically, is this effect more significant it increasing the mass of the atom or decreasing it's size?

Comment: @Michael  Lead has a face centered cubic crystalline structure while osmium crystallizes in a hexagonal close packed structure.  In **both** structures the lead and osmium atoms occupy around 74% of the volume, yet the densities of lead and osmium are very different (11.34 and 22.61 g/cm^3 respectively).  So I don't see how the crystal structure, *per se*, plays into the answer.  I fall back to unit cell size, which reflects osmium's small radius, and atomic weight. If I'm missing something, please elaborate.

Comment: @user3764899  The relativistic effects reduce the size of all orbitals that have significant density at the nucleus.  Therefore, all s and, to a lesser degree, p orbitals are contracted.  Osmium's 6s orbital (its outermost orbital) is consequently contracted, so overall osmium's size (atomic radius) is reduced.  Look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_radii_of_the_elements_(data_page)) and notice how osmium's radius sticks out like a sore thumb.  Its radius is by far the lowest for its atomic number.

Comment: @ron true. I wasn't saying that it's the only reason - but it definitely helps. A small size does not help if the structure is not close-packed.

Comment: Adding a discussion of packing fraction for various crystal structures would make this answer an A+. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_packing_factor

Comment: The argument about cell volumes is fallacious. Looking at molar volumes gives a more reasonable perspective. Pb = 207.2/11.34 = 18.27 cm^3/mole. Os = 190.23/22.59 = 8.421 cm^3/mole. So Os has a molar volume which is 46.09% of that for Pb.