# What explains the very high density of osmium and iridium?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, transition-metals, periodic-table

Iridium with a density of $22.56$ g cm<sup>-3</sup> & osmium with $22.59$ g cm<sup>-3</sup>. Data from their respective Wikipedia pages.

Only these two naturally occurring elements have such a high density. I wish to know why. Also If possible the factors affecting the density of any/every elemental substance.

Comment: [Welcome to chemistry.SE!](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) If you had any questions about the policies of our community, please ‎visit [the help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: Well, by definition, at least one element will be the densest. So you are asking why particular elements adopt a close-packed crystal structure (various reasons) and have heavy nuclei. I'm not sure that there is a 'simple' explanation for that.

Comment: The reasons behind osmium's density are explained [here](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/21662/why-is-osmium-the-densest-known-element)