Why aren't other elements with valence 6s electrons liquid like mercury?
I found out that mercury's 6s electrons undergo relativistic effects that make their pull to the nucleus greater, which makes it so that they can't bond with other atoms of mercury to form a solid. Why don't the other elements with a 6s electrons, such as tungsten, act as liquids if they both have 6s electrons?

Attributing bonding to 'relativistic effects' really irritates me. Yes, orbitals are different because of relativity. And they are different in every non-hydrogen atom from hydrogen-like orbitals. Note that mercury does form a solid, it just is stable below STP.

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/169007/lower-melting-points-of-zinc-cadmium-and-mercury https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/13667/why-does-mercury-have-low-melting-and-boiling-points

Because other elements with 3s valence electrons are not quite like magnesium. Mercury is not special at all in this regard.

@JonCuster It should not. QCH calculation not involving SR predicted Hg melting point +80 Deg C. With SR, with the error within +- 1 Deg C.

@Poutnik - there is no doubt that SR impacts atomic energy levels, which in turn influence condensed matter (liquid and crystalline) bonding. Which then influences more complex things like the electron plasma frequency that causes gold (and copper!) to have color (while silver has a plasma frequency up in the UV - go figure). The point is, saying 'relativistic effects' doesn't explain anything. Why do the SR-caused atomic energy level shifts cause the liquid to be more stable than the solid (remembering both are metallically bonded states). That 80K is under 7meV per atom.

80 deg C, not 80 K. // Room T solid gold, or caesium, are far from plasma.

The energy difference does not matter C or K - only delta…
